# How to get firestore id from query string?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-router-dom

So, the instruction from higher-ups was to get the Firestore id into a URL, inside some curly braces:

```
<Link to={`/details/{${val.id}}`}> done </Link>
```

Next step would be to render a component according to the data with that id. Unfortunatelly, neither,

```
  const [params, setParams] = useUrlSearchParams();

  return <div>__firebase_request_key: {params.__firebase_request_key}</div>;
```

nor

```
  let selectedId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("id");
```

have worked.

Ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useParams` in `react-router-dom` to get id: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Comment: like this? <Link to={`/kontakt/detalji/${val.id}`}> done </Link>, and 
  const { id } = useParams... Nope, console.log(id) returns undefined...

Comment: First, you declare
     `<Route path="/kontakt/detalji/:id">
        <YourComponent />
      </Route>`
Then. in `YourComponent`, just use `const { id } = useParams()`

Comment: got it the old way - with 'match'